# Setting 'name' in input [Vue.js]

Tags: vue.js

Is this legal in Vue?

```
<input :name="_charset_" />
```

Or should I do it like so:

```
<input name="_charset_" />
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `:name` actually binds the variable `_charset`'s value to the attribute, while `name` simply means setting `_charset_` as a string as the element's attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to put in layman's terms.

this is when `_charset_` is a variable which you have defined in `data()` or `computed`

```
  <input :name="_charset_" />
```

this is when `_charset_` is a literal string.

```
<input name="_charset_" />
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you bind data in Vue:

```
<input :name="_charset_" />
```

that is the shortcut for

```
<input v-bind:name="_charset_" />
```

obviously there must be a property called **_charset_**